# Accessing Master Page Controls in Non master page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

In asp.net, how can I access the master page controls in a non-master page?

Comment: Is the view that you're rendering using the master page that has the controls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the Masterpage as a property on your current page. However, the controls on your master page are protected so you can't access them directly. But you can access them by using `FindControl(string name)`. The code you need to use depends on if the control is inside or outside a content place holder.

```
// Gets a reference to a TextBox control inside a ContentPlaceHolder
ContentPlaceHolder mpContentPlaceHolder;
TextBox mpTextBox;
mpContentPlaceHolder = 
    (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
if(mpContentPlaceHolder != null)
{
    mpTextBox = (TextBox) mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("TextBox1");
    if(mpTextBox != null)
    {
        mpTextBox.Text = "TextBox found!";
    }
}

// Gets a reference to a Label control that is not in a 
// ContentPlaceHolder control
Label mpLabel = (Label) Master.FindControl("masterPageLabel");
if(mpLabel != null)
{
    Label1.Text = "Master page label = " + mpLabel.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add this in your webPage to access the contents of master page [Master Page : programatically access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/xxwa0ff0.aspx)

```
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="Your MasterPath" %>
```

you can do like this (alternative way )

```
MasterPage mstr 
Label lbl
mstr = Page.Master
If (mstr.ID == "yourMasterIDString")
{
     lbl = mstr.FindControl("lblBar")
        If (lbl !=null)
          {
                lbl.Text = "Do some Logic"
          }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use can

```
TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)this.Master.FindControl("MytxtBox");
txt1.Text="Content Changed from content page";
```